# Area of a folded paper

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, geometry, derivatives

One corner of a rectangular sheet of paper is folded over so as to reach the opposite edge(lengthwise) of the sheet. If area of the folded paper is minimum, show the crease divided the width in 2:3.

Note: We can use double derivative concept to encounter this problem. I don't understand the geometry the sum portrays. Please if possible post an image.

Answer (score 2):

Have you picked up a piece of paper and folded it?  The dotted line shows where the triangle came from.  The triangles above and below the highest diagonal line are supposed to be congruent.  You want to maximize the area of the folded part, which minimizes the area left.

[image]